# Typing in an open text/word file in real time with eclipse

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that creates a new word document and types in it at a certain speed while it is open.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to type words in a document in real time.  There are questions on this site that are similar, but they are for C++ and Python.  Furthermore, these methods have no way to regulate typing speed.  I am using Eclipse and would prefer not to use any plugins.

Comment: What language?  Have you tried anything?  Can you provide a sample of the code you have already attempted?

Comment: I am using java in eclipse.  I actually have not been able to figure out anything in terms of what works and what doesn't.  I am fairly inexperienced at programming and do not have a very large knowledge of the java coding language.  I am also trying to figure out how to open a word document located within the project folder in order to get around using a plugin to create a new word document, but that I am saving for a different question.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  The language used to create Word macro programs is Visual Basic.

Comment: My goal is a program that, when run, opens word after a certain amount of delay and starts typing words in it in a way that looks like a person is doing it.  Kind of like one of those dictated messages without the dictation.  I would incorporate a random generator and have it type in random strings to make it seem less systematic.